# php created image pixelated

Tags: php, jcrop

I made an app where the user can upload an image, crop it with jCrop and then it's send to him via email.
Everything works as expected, but the php script that creates the image seems to reduce the quality a bit while cropping/resizing. It's not extreme, but I need the same resolution as the image that has been uploaded. I had imagejpg() and changed it with imagepng(), without success.
Maybe you can help me.
Here's the code:

```
list($oWidth, $oHeight) = getimagesize($_POST["hiddenSrc"]);
$xPos = $_POST["x1h"];
$yPos = $_POST["y1h"];
$targ_w = $_POST["wh"];
$targ_h = $_POST["hh"];
$jpeg_quality = 9;

$src = $_POST["hiddenSrc"];


if(mime_content_type($src) == "image/jpeg")
{
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
else if(mime_content_type($src) == "image/png")
{
    $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$xPos,$yPos,$targ_w,$targ_h,$targ_w,$targ_h);

if(!file_exists('../FOLDER/'.$_SESSION['foldername'].'/PRODUKT'.$_SESSION['productNameCount'].'.png'))
{
            imagepng($dst_r,"../FOLDER/".$_SESSION['foldername']."/PRODUKT".$_SESSION['productNameCount'].".png",$jpeg_quality);
}
```

The rest of the script is just creating the folder and other stuff that is not related with the image

Thank you very much!

The rest is just some functions determinining that the image's not too small, ect.

Here's a before/after comparison:

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

I know the difference is slight, but it is very visible when the image is printed

Comment: As an aside, bear in mind that on a case-sensitive filesystem (common on Unix servers) the file you're checking existence of will be different from the file you're writing, as you've written "produkt" in one place and "PRODUKT" in the other. You should probably create the path once as a variable and use that in both places.

Comment: jep, you're right,thanks. I fixed it ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem.

I transfered the uploaded image to a data-url which reduced the quality. If I directly upload the image file the quality stays the same.
(+ I'm using Imagemagick)

But now I'm having trouble with quality loss while resizing the images, but that's another story and another thread ;)

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case it is related to the value you use for compression.

for imagejpeg: quality is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75).

for imagepng: Compression level from 0 (no compression) to 9.

Here is an example for what could be the result in your case:

```
list($oWidth, $oHeight) = getimagesize($_POST["hiddenSrc"]);
$xPos = $_POST["x1h"];
$yPos = $_POST["y1h"];
$targ_w = $_POST["wh"];
$targ_h = $_POST["hh"];

$src = $_POST["hiddenSrc"];


if(mime_content_type($src) == "image/jpeg")
{
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $jpeg_quality = 90;
}
else if(mime_content_type($src) == "image/png")
{
    $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    $png_quality = 0;
}

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$xPos,$yPos,$targ_w,$targ_h,$targ_w,$targ_h);

if(!file_exists('../FOLDER/'.$_SESSION['foldername'].'/produkt'.$_SESSION['productNameCount'].'.png'))
{
            imagepng($dst_r,"../FOLDER/".$_SESSION['foldername']."/PRODUKT".$_SESSION['productNameCount'].".png",$png_quality);
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that for PNG files, it's only the size of the actual file that will be affected by the compression value; the image quality will remain the same. (For PNG files, the compression value is basically input to the zlib library's compression factor for data compressing the final result; it doesn't change the underlying image data.)

Comment: thanks, I had the same before with only jpeg and set the quality to 100, but it doesn't seem to make the quality even to the original images.

Comment: I tried your solution, but nothing changed :( I don't know the resized image seems like it's too sharp so the strong colours are overexposed and te are not completely sharp. I 'll add a before/after comparison.

Comment: @user2839873 If the colours are significantly different, it might also be a problem with the embedded colour profile in the original image as well as the overall quality. I'm sure your examples will be useful, but sadly I won't be able to see them until I'm at home; our work firewall blocks everything from imgur :(

Comment: They aren't just not as crisp as it should be.

Comment: I updated the post with all the main functions, maybe it has something to do with jCrop itself

Comment: have you tried to apply anti-aliasing in php using imageantialias ? imageantialias($image true); Concerning jCrop from what I've seen it is only used to get lengths not to actually resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$jpeg_quality = 9;
```

with

```
$jpeg_quality = 100;
```

you can use any value between zero and 100

Comment: hey, I already tried that, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem